# C++ can't access child property from parent

Tags: c++, inheritance

Can anybody explain why `Driver` `init()` method is unable to print `name` property overridden in child?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Driver {
public:
    std::string name = "Unknown";

    void init() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
};

// need public here to inherit init()
class SpecificDriver : public Driver {
public:
    std::string name = "Specific";

};

int main() {
    Driver d;
    SpecificDriver sd;

    // this gives Unknown Unknown =/
    d.init();
    sd.init();
}
```

This gives:

```
Unknown
Unknown
```

And should be:

```
Unknown
Specific
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae5380798d9a4731)

Comment: I will pose the question: Is it more important that the value of a property be different in the derived class or that the action that init performs is different in the derived class. Or both Perhaps? If you need just the value of "name" to be different you could use my method, but if you need init to something else in the derived version you could use the method proposed by Chris Beck

Comment: I need to value of property to be different - the name of driver is only needed to be output in debug mode, and all debug code is in parent `init()`.

Comment: @AlexZywicki and readability is important too - I still not able to read/understand the code with initializers (reading tutorial right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, virtual inheritance is opt-in and not implicit.

When you have this code

```
class Driver {
public:
    std::string name = "Unknown";

    void init() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
};
```

the symbol `name` will be resolved statically based on what is in scope at that time.

If you later declare a global variable `name` it has no effect on the meaning of this code. If you later derive from this class `Driver`, the `init` function when it is inherited for that class, won't have a different meaning, as in your example.

This "static" dispatch is the default behavior in C++ because it is the simplest and fastest. Especially, it is important that it works this way if you are doing things with templates and inheritance later, otherwise lots of code would have lots of extra overhead.

Alex Zywicki shows one way that you could achieve what you want. Another way would be to use virtual dispatch to get the string. Something like this:

```
class Driver {
public:
    virtual std::string name() const {
        return "Unknown";
    }

    void init() {
        std::cout << name() << std::endl;
    }
};

class SpecificDriver : public Driver {
    virtual std::string name() const override {
        return "Specific";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes `name` a method. Is it possible to use `virtual dispatch` for `name` leaving it as a property?

Comment: I agree that this approach would most likely be the most scalable and simple solution to the problem. This is how i would usually design something in this situation, my proposed method was the simplest revision of the original code but by no means the best way to achieve the results

Comment: virtual dispatch only applies to member functions/methods you cannot declare a property as virtual, you would have to either choose the method proposed by Chris Beck or by me. But it is not possible to combine the two

Comment: @AlexZywicki thanks for clarification. I'd use the way with methods, because it is more simple for me now. Initializers are still a bit cryptic for someone coming from Python.

Comment: When you say "initializers" do you mean constructors? or inline initialization of member variables. as in `std::string name = "value";`

Comment: @AlexZywicki "initializers" for me is `Driver():name("unknown"){}` - this thing. I don't get why `SpecificDriver():name("Specific")` would not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112567/discussion-between-alex-zywicki-and-anatoly-techtonik).

Answer (score 5):

You are not doing quite what you think you may be. You are declaring a variable "name" in driver and a variable "name" in SpecificDriver. When you call `init()` defined in base class driver, that driver can only access its own `name` field with value "unknown".

Instead you should initialize the "name" variable using a constructor.

Like this:

```
class Driver {
public:
    std::string name;

    Driver():name("Unknown"){} //default
    Driver(std::string value):name(value){}

    void init() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
};

// need public here to inherit init()
class SpecificDriver : public Driver {
public:
    SpecificDriver():Driver("Specific"){}
};

int main() {
    Driver d;
    SpecificDriver sd;

    d.init();
    sd.init();
}
```

Edit: Live Demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c453758867454348

Comment: This doesn't look like classic inheritance. So, the answer is that it is impossible to access child properties // methods from parent in C++? Because it is the same with methods http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ced69529a69dd18d

Comment: See the comment i posted above on your question and below on the answer from Chris Beck

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the class member of the child class through [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
class Driver {
public:
    void init() {
        std::cout << static_cast<Derived*>(this)->name << std::endl;
        std::cout << Derived::value << std::endl;
    }
};

class SpecificDriver : public Driver<SpecificDriver> {
public:
    std::string name = "Specific";
    static constexpr char* value = "Another specific string";
};

int main() {
    SpecificDriver g;
    g.init();
}
```

If you need a common base class for storing these in, or combining with normal polymorphic behavior you can make the template class `Driver` inherit from a common base class.